# Windows Store App not Scaling

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, multi-dimensional-scaling

I am developing a Windows Store app, and I hit a problem with scaling to different screen sizes - namely, 140 and 180%.  Everything works perfectly on my computer, which is scaled to 100%, but when I test it on the Surface Pro and on the different simulator options that are not scaled to 100%, it starts acting up.  I am pretty sure the problem is with the `<VisualStateManager>` but that is about as far as I can tell.

The problem only appears in the `Snapped` state, and what happens is in Landscape mode at 140%, the title sometimes appears and sometimes stays blank.  Sometimes, clicking the title works to bring up the menu - even if it is blank, while other times nothing happens.  The curious part about it is that somehow whether or not it works depends on the data loaded in the `DataFrame` frame, so if I change the content of those pages to the same content as a working page, it works.  The shorter pages appear to have more problems, but that is the only pattern I can find.

When the screen is scaled to 140% portrait mode, none of the text is visible, but some is still clickable.

When the screen is scaled to 180%, the text is not visible, not is it clickable.

Image of title not showing:

[image: Title Not Showing]

Image with title showing:

[image: Title Showing]

This is my `MainPage.xaml` code:

```
<Page
    x:Name="mainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LearnOneNote"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="LearnOneNote.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Margin="-2">

    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:StringToTitleConverter x:Key="Convert" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" x:Name="TitleRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" x:Name="ItemsColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="DataColumn"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="Items" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" Padding="5" SelectionChanged="newSelect" Tapped="Items_Tapped"/>

        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,10" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Brown" MaxHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

        <Viewbox x:Name="TitleView" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Brown" Text="{Binding ElementName=Items, Path=SelectedValue, ConverterParameter=PrimaryView, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <Viewbox x:Name="TitleViewSnapped" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleSnapped" Foreground="Brown" Text="{Binding ElementName=Items, Path=SelectedValue, ConverterParameter=Snapped, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}"
                       Margin="0,10,5,5" PointerEntered="Title_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Title_PointerExited" Tapped="Title_Tapped"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,0,20" x:Name="DataFrame" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryView"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsColumn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleViewSnapped" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ItemsSelector">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DataColumn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsColumn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Items" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="25"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If I delete this bit from `<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">`, I have no problem with my text disappearing, although the clicking problem is still there:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Title" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=Items, Path=SelectedValue, ConverterParameter=Snapped, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I searched the internet for other people having this problem and found these MSDN pages:

[Scaling to Pixel Density](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx)
[Resizing to Narrow Layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx)
[Support Multiple Screen Sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465349.aspx)

I have already made all of these changes to the best of my knowledge.

My simplified program is available in files [here](https://github.com/user2509848/WPF)

My images are available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APc7X.jpg)

Comment: It might be off topic, but note that there is no concept of a snapped state in the APIs for Windows 8.1 anymore. It's up to you to provide different layouts for different window sizes.

Comment: @FilipSkakun Yes, I just am used to the terminology, so I named my visual states "PrimaryView", "Snapped", and "ItemsSelector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have bindings in animations. I'd try two separate `TextBlocks` that bind to different values and alternate `Visibility` of these in visual state storyboards if different text is how you want to differentiate between views.

Comment: Good idea - that is about the one thing I haven't tried.

Comment: Update - this did solve the problem of the title not displaying; however, I still have a problem with the click not working.

Comment: Do you handle the tapped event on the new TextBlock?

Comment: As a clarification, the click only doesn't work sporadically at certain scalings.

Comment: I saw people complaining the `Tapped` event doesn't work sometimes when you tap quickly multiple times. Otherwise - your `TextBlock ` might be too small and so you might need to use a larger hit test area. I'd recommend using a `Button` control instead of a `TextBlock` to handle clicks. You might need to restyle it or perhaps use `HyperlinkButton` to make it look more like a label, but it will give you support for keyboard, mouse hover and pressed visual states etc. Scaling text with a `Viewbox` is usually bad design.

Comment: Well, I did try using a Button, but it had exactly the same problems.  As for my textblock possibly being too small, it is not because I have the color set to change when I hover over it, and the text is quite large, so it is easily clickable.  I will take your recommendation about the button anyway, though.

Comment: I solved it, see my solution below for details.  Also, I tried just using the one textblock and changing the binding, and it does work now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is absolutely crazy.  I solved my problem by removing the margin of -2 on the page:

```
<Page
  x:Name="mainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:LearnOneNote"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  x:Class="LearnOneNote.MainPage"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Margin="-2">
```

becomes:

```
<Page
  x:Name="mainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:LearnOneNote"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  x:Class="LearnOneNote.MainPage"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Everything started working immediately in all scale sizes, although I have a thin white line around my page.  Any information on why this did this and how to remove that white line is welcome.

Comment: You have a Grid with `Background="White"` in your XAML